# Sum different rows in data frame based on two columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For the group where variable 1 is True. I want to sum the column Number in the row where variable 2 is false to the other two rows where variable 2 is True.

```
   Variable 1  Variable 2  Number
0        True        True      10
1        True        True      20
2        True       False      30
3       False       False       5
```

***Expected output:***

```
   Variable 1  Variable 2  Number
0        True        True      40
1        True        True      50
2        True       False      30
3       False       False       5
```

If it's possible I would like the code to work for multiple groups where variable 1 is true.

Comment: Please, consider explain this:   (Question A). When variable 1 is True and variable 2 True: What to do
(Question B). When variable 1 is True but variable 2 is False: What to do
(Question C). When variable 1 is False but variable 2 is True: What to do

Comment: @AndreNevares Question C: if both variable 1 & 2 are false: Do nothing, keep Number as it's. Question B: when variable 1 is True but variable 2 is False: keep Number as it's. Question A: Number = Number + Number (from row where variable 1 is True but variable is false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop or anything complex. Use simple boolean indexing for in place modification:

```
m1 = df['Variable 1']
m2 = df['Variable 2']

# add to the rows where m1 AND m2
# the sum of rows where m1 AND NOT m2
df.loc[m1&m2, 'Number'] += df.loc[m1&~m2, 'Number'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   Variable 1  Variable 2  Number
0        True        True      40
1        True        True      50
2        True       False      30
3       False       False       5
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this what you are expecting, if you run the below code you will get the expected output.

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Variable 1':[True,True,True,False],'Variable 2':[True,True,False,False], 'Number': [10,20,30,5]}
stack = []
for i in range(len(data['Variable 1'])):
    if data['Variable 1'][i] and data['Variable 2'][i]:
        stack.append((i, data['Number'][i]))
    elif  data['Variable 1'][i] and not  data['Variable 2'][i]:
        while len(stack) > 0:
            a,b = stack.pop()
            data['Number'][a] = data['Number'][a] +  data['Number'][i]  

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Please feel free to comment if this is not your case. Thanks and hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @y051, thank you a lot for your help. Is there a way to do this without a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

It was a little bit hard to understand what you want...
my solution is very explicity...
I Tried to guide you step by step...

#### My code

```py
import pandas as pd

# your sample data as a dict
data={'Variable 1':[True,True,True,False],'Variable 2':[True,True,False,False], 'Number': [10,20,30,5]}

# create a dataframe from created dict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

# replace empty spaces from name columns so you can use DOT NOTATION
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_').str.lower()

# What to do in case at least one is false
df['both_false'] = 0 + df.number[(df.variable_1 == False) | (df.variable_2 == False)]
df['both_false'] = df['both_false'].fillna(0)

# What to do in case Both True
df['both_true'] = 0 + df.number[(df.variable_1 == True) & (df.variable_2 == True)].sum()

# Calc 1
df['result_1'] = df.loc[(df.variable_1 == True) & (df.variable_2 == True), 'number'] + df.loc[(df.variable_1 == True) & (df.variable_2 == True), 'both_true']  
df['result_1'] = df['result_1'].fillna(0)

# Calc 2
df['result_2'] = df.loc[(df.variable_1 == False) | (df.variable_2 == False), 'number'] 
df['result_2'] = df['result_2'].fillna(0)

# Final result in both cases
df['result'] = df.result_1 + df.result_2

# just drop unecessary series 
df.drop(['both_false', 'both_true', 'result_1', 'result_2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

#### Output

| - | variable_1 | variable_2 | number | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | True | True | 10 | 40.0 |
| 1 | True | True | 20 | 50.0 |
| 2 | True | False | 30 | 30.0 |
| 3 | False | False | 5 | 5.0 |

Hope that helps you